# create django model with field names from list

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model in my models.py file like this:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    player = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    apples = models.IntegerField()
    bananas = models.IntegerField()
```

Where each "player" has different numbers of fruits in his inventory. I will change the possible fruits over time, thus I would like to create these fields dynamically from a list. So right now the list would be ["apples", "bananas"] but at a later point in time I would like to have ["apples", "oranges", "lemons"]. Is there a way to create the field names from a list?

Comment: No there isn't. But this should be a different model, `Fruit` and you should use a many-to-many relationship, possibly with a "through" relation in order to track the number of each fruit for each player. Check the django docs for many-to-many relations and "through" relationships.

Comment: thanks, I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at models.ManyToManyField, and using a though-relationship.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Inventory(models.Model):
    player = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fruits = models.ManyToManyField(
        Fruit,
        through='FruitContent'
    )

class FruitContent(models.Model):
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit, models.CASCADE)
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    # Protect your data structure
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['fruit', 'inventory'], name='unique_ownership')
        ]
```

That's with keeping your Inventory model, but that's really a bit awkward way of doing it. I would prefer something like this:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    inventory = models.ManyToManyField(
        Fruit,
        through='PlayerFruits'
    )

class PlayerFruits(models.Model):
    fruit = models.ForeignKey(Fruit, models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    # Protect your data structure
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['fruit', 'player'], name='unique_ownership')
```